# Using CSS with React/JSX

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This may be a very simple question but I cannot figure out how to use CSS with React.
I have heard of inline styles but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.

More so, if I use CSS where do I apply it to considering all my HTML is JSX within the react class. So I would not be able to do normal CSS i.e

```
.className{

}
```

One of my react classes contains this code:

```
render: function() {

    return (
        <div>
          <h1> Todos </h1>

          <form className="todoForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter task"
                value={this.state.text}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            <input
                type="submit"
                value="Submit todo"
                />
          </form>

          <h4> List of todos: </h4>

          <ToDoList deleteItem={this.deleteItem} listItems={this.state.submittedValues}/>
        </div>
    );
```

How would I say make the input box in the form have a green background or how would I make the `<h1> heading` blue in font? In CSS I would just have a css file link it to html and say: `h1 { color: blue };`
cant quite see it in react though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a className for input type="text"

```
<input type='text' className='exText' />
```

for Ur CSS 
.exText {
background: 'green'
}

please use className as a attributes to the component and use the components name with . if it is a className and # if its id.

Answer (score 2):

[Ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)

**Html**

```
<h1 style={styles.heading}>
```

**Inline Style**

```
let styles = {
   heading: {
     fontColor: '#00f'
   };
}
```

Comment: Put it in end after closing of your class.

Comment: `<h1 style={styles.heading}> Todos </h1> ...... Uncaught ReferenceError: styles is not defined`. also at the end of what class?

Comment: In the class where you have written render.